# Sublime Text font directory

Tags: text, fonts, directory, settings

Is there any possibility to change default font directory in sublime text? I just want to use font stored on my pendrive using portable sublime text so I don't have to install font on every machine I use my portable sublime text.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything for Sublime Text specifically (it only seems to list system-registered fonts), but I've described my semi-portable solution for loading custom fonts without admin rights (on Windows), which allows me to use any font I want [including with Sublime Text](https://www.dsebastien.net/2015/10/06/so-fond-of-fonts/)

More specifically, I'm using the [regfont](http://www.marshwiggle.net/regfont) utility to register fonts in my user session (doesn't require admin privileges).

The downside is that the operation must be done whenever a new session is started.