# Sublime Text Font from file

Tags: sublimetext3

I have ST as a portable version and use a custom font, but don't have admin rights at my work place to install it. Can you somehow point `"font_face":` to a local .ttf file?

I'm aware of [the possibility regfont](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535801/sublime-text-font-directory), but that's a clunky hack.
For my build system I use `"cmd" : ["${packages}/../../../MSYS2/mingw64/bin/gcc"`, but such a path doesn't work with `font_face` as it seemingly doesn't accept .ttf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime doesn't load font files directly in any way, it uses the face name you use in the setting to look up the appropriate font in the OS's font catalog (in a manner that depends on the operating system it's running on) so that it can use that font for rendering.

As such if you want to use a font in Sublime I believe your only option is to use some utility such as the one you mentioned in your question to temporarily register a font with your OS so that Sublime can see it.

Comment: Ok thanks clarifying.
I wrote a batch file that registers the used font, before launching. Not as elegant but works I guess.